# Reasons why Alert, Confirm and Prompt dont work when run inside a browser control of C# client

Tags: javascript, c#, html, browser, alert

I have a WinForm in in .NET with a browser control.

I have created a basic html page with some javascript for testing and im displaying it in the control.

The HTML renders fine and all other javascript seems to work perfectly fine, however the 3 javascript functions dont seem to do anything. They are just ignored.

```
<script>

    function TestFuncs()
    {
        alert("hello");
        confirm("please confirm?");
        prompt("Enter data");
    }

</script>

<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="TestFuncs()">
```

The above does not prompt with anything at all. I added some other logic to the TestFuncs to confirm its being called and it is. So for some reason these popup alerts and prompts dont work from my browser control.

Any insight into this would be appreciated? Could it be something i need to do to get it to work, or could it be a limitation of the browser control in .NET?

Comment: I can't test this right now, but it looks like you need to set [`ScriptErrorsSuppressed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_ScriptErrorsSuppressed) to `false`.

Comment: Money quote: "When ScriptErrorsSuppressed is set to true, the WebBrowser control hides all its dialog boxes that originate from the underlying ActiveX control, not just script errors"

Comment: Thanks guys. Im not using the standard .NET WebBrowser control directly so didnt think of this. However the control i am using is a wrapper around this. I decompiled it and sure enough they are setting ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true.